# implement authentication and authorization to user

Tags: authentication, list-authors, multi-author

i want to get authentication to my website like to be the page with name and password as a file reference to log in as visitor with detected authorization to each person want to visit the website

how i can set up the file user to check in and how can give authorization to each one can access .

Comment: you can create new users, read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Users_-_Your_Blogging_Family

Comment: What do you mean by **"as a file reference to log in as visitor"**? Please clarify the question.

Comment: mean save the database of the  visitors  in file if he authorized to login okay

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a plugin.

[Ultimate Member – User Profile & Membership Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) is a good one.

Activate it on your site, then in the settings you can limit your site to be accessed only by logged in users. If they are not logged in, you can redirect them to the login page.

Make sure to uncheck the "Allow Homepage to be accessible" checkbox.

Comment: but how give the visitor authorization to access some pages not all

Comment: If you want to restrict access to some pages, this plugin might be better.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/

Comment: You could then restrict certain pages based on user roles, for example limit certain pages/posts to only be accessible by "Subscribers".

All the user management is taken care of by WordPress.

You will need to make sure registration is set up for your site. This is in Settings/General - Check "Anyone can register".

This will allow people to register for your site and view the restricted content.

Comment: thanks for your answer   but is there a plugin to give permission based on name/ email  not role of the visitor ..this is as i want to restrict  page to available to one visitor not other ?

Comment: I would probably try and use the built in WordPress user system if you can. You could manually add a user. An email address is required for this. Then set up a custom role to manage access. E.g. if a user is registered on your site, you could give them a custom role of "Allowed to View" and set up the page to allow access for this particular role. Or you could give a user a custom role of "Not Allowed to View" and restrict access to this user. Custom roles can be set up using the "Members" plugin mentioned before -  wordpress.org/plugins/members under "Users/Add New Role".